# Does tf.keras.layers.Conv2D as first layer in model truly need input_shape?

Tags: tensorflow, keras-layer

According to [the official document](https://www.tensorflow.org/api_docs/python/tf/keras/layers/Conv2D) on `tf.keras.layers.Conv2D`,

> When using this layer as the first layer in a model, provide the keyword argument input_shape (tuple of integers, does not include the sample axis), e.g. input_shape=(128, 128, 3) for 128x128 RGB pictures in data_format="channels_last".

but actually without input_shape it does work in both graph execution and eager execution environment.

In graph execution,

```
import tensorflow as tf
from tensorflow.keras.layers import Conv2D, Flatten, Dense

class CNN(tf.keras.Model):

    def __init__(self):
        super(CNN, self).__init__()
        self.conv = Conv2D(1, 3, padding='same', data_format='channels_first')
        self.flatten = Flatten()
        self.dense = Dense(1)

    def call(self, inputs):
        x = self.conv(inputs)
        x = self.flatten(x)
        return self.dense(x)


cnn = CNN()
inputs = tf.random_uniform([2, 3, 16, 16])
outputs = cnn(inputs)

with tf.Session() as sess:
    sess.run(tf.global_variables_initializer())
    outputs = sess.run(outputs)
    print(outputs)
```

works without any error and in eager execution,

```
import tensorflow as tf
from tensorflow.keras.layers import Conv2D, Flatten, Dense
tf.enable_eager_execution()

class CNN(tf.keras.Model):
    def __init__(self):
        super(CNN, self).__init__()
        self.conv = Conv2D(1, 3, padding='same', data_format='channels_first')
        self.flatten = Flatten()
        self.dense = Dense(1)

    def call(self, inputs):
        x = self.conv(inputs)
        x = self.flatten(x)
        return self.dense(x)


cnn = CNN()
inputs = tf.random_uniform([2, 3, 16, 16])
outputs = cnn(inputs)
print(outputs)
```

also does.

Q1: Does `tf.keras.layers.Conv2D` as the first layer in a model truly need to specifying `input_shape`?

Q2: If not, when is it needed and why is it mentioned so in the official document?

UPDATE1:
[Tutorial on tf.keras](https://www.tensorflow.org/tutorials/eager/custom_layers#layers_common_sets_of_useful_operations) says

> The number of input dimensions is often unnecessary, as it can be inferred
>   the first time the layer is used, but it can be provided if you want to 
>   specify it manually, which is useful in some complex models.

UPDATE2:
`git blame` of docstring in TensorFlow source revealed that this document is copied from Keras API (which is not TensorFlow keras API).

Answer (score 1):

Convolution does generally does not need an input shape. Actually you can feed the same network different input shapes, but it is much faster, when you give tensorflow an input shape. I think that the reason, why its stated in the docs.

The original method of tensorflow does not even have an argument for input shapes.

Comment: Thanks! BTW, what does `The original method of tensorflow` refer to?

Comment: If your answer is right, can I fix the `input_shape` not at initialization but at build time? Or should this question be asked another thread?

Comment: Under the hood `tf.nn.conv2d` is used. (https://www.tensorflow.org/api_docs/python/tf/nn/conv2d) but keras calls the C++ API and not python.

Comment: What do you mean with fix?

Comment: fix means to specify. In other words, can I specify `input_shape` not at initialization but at build time?

Comment: I don't understood how the fact that keras calls the C++ API and not python is related to this answer.

Comment: Maybe it means keras does not call `tf.nn.conv2d` explicitly in python, but implicitly calls it through C++ API?

Comment: Even if I specify `input_shape` of `tf.keras.layers.Conv2D` and pass inputs with different shape from it to the layer, it does not raise any error in eager mode. It seems that the given `input_shape` is ignored.

Comment: Yes you're right. It calls it implicitly. Yeah I think this is wanted, but it will have an impact on performance I guess.

Comment: I did an additional experiment to confirm your answer. Comparison on execution time with 100 convolutional layers network with and without input_shape in eager execution provides no difference in execution time per call.

Comment: Ok, I rembered the performance issue in an article, but may this information is obsolete.